# cout << "text" gets displayed only part of the time

Tags: c++, buffer, flush, cout

I learned the hard way about using endl at the end of a cout statement to flush the buffer. What I'm confused about is why endl is only necessary sometimes. Usually I can just do

```
cout << "test";
```

And it will display test. But in the middle of a long console program I'll have a similar cout statement and nothing will display and the code won't move on. Adding endl to the end fixes the problem by flushing the buffer and displaying the text. But what causes the buffer to be automatically flushed in the some cases and manually flushed in others? I can't provide any sample code because I don't know how to reproduce the problem, but I'm assuming most of you have seen this.

Comment: Most libraries flush at the newline character `\n` so if you terminate with that no `endl` is needed. Also you can of course use `flush` instead if you don't want a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the buffer reaches a certain length or the program terminates normally, the buffer is flushed.

Comment: If I write cout << "test1"; cin >> var; the program doesn't terminate but waits for var to be inputed. However, test1 is still displayed. So did the buffer reach this "certain length"? How do you know what that is?

Comment: @gsingh2011 I guess `cin` flushes the buffer then. After all, you can't input without displaying what came before.

Comment: If you think about what cin does, it makes perfect sense that it would first flush any output to the screen.

Comment: @gsingh2011: when cin is used cout is flushed to prevent problems like writing after input while in code it's the other way. The buffer size is implementation detail and I'm not sure you can query it.

Answer (score 1):

When and why the buffer is flushed automatically is up to the implementers of the particular platform you're working on. You shouldn't make any assumptions or guesses about when the buffer will be flushed.

When you want to display text, just add the std::endl. ;)